# Meaning full name from content provider

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

Trying to figure out how to get a meaning full name of an custom user related location through an content provider on the device for example an SD Card. In case of the emulator wanted to display "Virtual SD Card" instead of "BA11-150F".

Letting the user pick a folder via the `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` intent to choose where to store/retrieve data. With the result from the content provider tried already the [DocumentContract](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/DocumentsContract.html), [ContentProviderClient](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProviderClient.html) and [ContentResolver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html) to get a meaning full name. By querying the root URI with [buildRootsUri](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/DocumentsContract.html#buildRootsUri(java.lang.String)) got an insufficient permission exception.

[TotalCommander](http://www.ghisler.com/android.htm) is able to readout this information...how is that possible?